# Increased API response time due to Cloudflare DNS proxy

Tags: rest, amazon-ec2, dns, response, cloudflare

I am working on a REST API server. API server is hosted on AWS Asia Pacific (Mumbai) Region. When I tried hitting API directly with AWS EC2 machine IP, the response time is approximately 50-60ms.

I added an `A record` with proxy on Cloudflare and then my response time for the same API increased to 350-400ms, which is almost 6-7times higher.
[image]

It is expected to have some latency due to the Cloudflare proxy but this seems to be too high.

I have already tried disabling the cache, browser integrity checks, and always online settings, but nothing worked.
One of the possible reasons can be the Cloudflare servers located in the US. I tried to get the server IP using `traceroute`, it is US IP.

What is wrong here? Is there any way to set the Cloudflare server as near as possible to India to reduce the latency?

Comment: Hi Tarun, can you please add the RTT for your Cloudflare `traceroute`? The Cloudflare IP being a US IP does not mean much as it usually indicates where the IP is "registered". I suspect Cloudflare's location is in physically close proximity, and the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare is essentially an anycast network. Which means the routing is based on your peering / local ISP.

Cloudflare defaults to the nearest DC to route your requests. But the weird part about BGP is if there are no agreement then some routes are unreachable.

This however can be requested to Cloudflare, if you're on any of the premium tier.